# Probability variable exceeds another

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Suppose we have a biased coin with probability $\frac13$ heads and
> $\frac23$ tails. If we flip this coin $n$ times, what is the
> probability we have more heads than tails?

Is this something we can solve for? My best idea is to use a tail inequality such as Markov's Inequality or Chebychev's Inequality to form an upper bound but curious if there is a simple way to get the true probability. Only other thing I can think of is to brute force small cases of $n$ and see if a pattern exists.

Comment: Let $p = \frac{1}{3}$ be the probability of heads. Your desired probability is $\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor \frac{1}{2} (n - 1) \rfloor} \binom{n}{k} (1 - p)^k p^{n - k}$.

Comment: If all you are interested in is an estimation, you can relate this to the normal distribution.  There will be an average of $np$ "successes" (*here $n\times \frac{1}{3}$ heads*) with a standard deviation of $\sqrt{npq}$ with $q=1-p$ (*equal to $\frac{2}{3}$ here*).  As for "*the true probability*" if you have a strong enough computer or calculator, this is simply going to be $\sum\limits_{k=\lceil \frac{n+1}{2}\rceil}^n \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$

Comment: Of course, with $n=1000$ or so, there is little point in trying to find the exact probability... with an average of $\approx 333$ and a standard deviation of $\approx 14.9$, we have more heads than tails would be more than 11 standard deviations away from the mean... occurring with a near zero probability, on the order of $10^{-28}$.  The numbers being added in the sum would likely be too small for most calculators to handle.  With $n$ even larger this becomes even closer to zero probability.

Comment: @K.Jiang thank you, that makes sense. Why are you summing from $k = 0$ to $\frac12(n-1)$? If there are more heads shouldn't be from $\floor{\frac{n}2}+1$ to $n$?

Comment: They phrased their sum with $k$ as the number of tails.  It doesn't make much difference in the end

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_n$ and $T_n$ be the number of heads and tails, respectively, in $n$ flips. Since $H_n+T_n=n$ for all positive integers $n$, we have
$$ P[H_n\geq T_n] = P[H_n\geq n/2] \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Let $X_i$ be an indicator function that is 1 if flip $i$ is heads, and 0 else, so
$$H_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$
Assume $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. $Bern(p)$ with $p=1/3$. You can use the Hoeffding inequality
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

$$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\geq np + t\right] \leq \exp(-2t^2/n)\quad \forall t>0, n\in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$

We can choose $t$ so that $np+t=n/2$:
$$ t = n(1/2-p) = n/6$$
So
$$\boxed{P[H_n\geq T_n] \leq \exp(-n/18) \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}}$$
For $n$ even, you can compare this to the exact
$$ P[H_n\geq T_n]=\sum_{i=n/2}^{n} {n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \quad \forall n \in \{2, 4, 6, ...\}$$
Truncating to 5 decimal places gives
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%3Dsum+%28n+choose+i%29%281%2F3%29%5Ei%282%2F3%29%5E%28n-i%29%2Ci%3D%28n%2F2%29..n%2C+n%3D90

- $n=18$: $(exact, bound) = (0.10760, 0.36787)$
- $n=36$: $(exact, bound) = (0.02834, 0.13533)$
- $n=54$: $(exact, bound) = (0.00827, 0.04978)$
- $n=72$: $(exact, bound)  = (0.00252, 0.01831)$
- $n=90$: $(exact, bound) = (0.00079, 0.00673)$

For $n=1000$, Wolfram-Alpha does not give a meaningful answer for the exact sum, but the bound is
$$P[H_{1000}\geq T_{1000}]\leq e^{-1000/18} = 7.45639 \times 10^{-25}$$